# Im getting the following error : name 'doctor_id' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get objects from a database onto a webpage but I seem to keep getting the following error.
The framework I'm using is Django

Error: (it occurs in the views.py incase you were wondering)

```
name 'doctor_id' is not defined
```

The views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Doctors
    
def test2(request):
    doctor = Doctors.objects.all()
    selected_item2 = get_object_or_404(Doctors, pk=doctor_id)
    Doctors.doctor = selected_item2
    Doctors.save()
    return render(request, 'website/test2.html', {})
```

The models.py is:

```
class Doctors(models.Model):
    dname = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ddept = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    dphone = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    demail = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    dimage = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'portfolio/images')
```

Comment: So where does `doctor_id` come from before you're using it here: `selected_item2 = get_object_or_404(Doctors, pk=doctor_id)`?

Comment: you probably meant `doctor.id` but then that still wouldn't make sense since `doctor` is multiple doctors. Not only that if you did mean `doctor.id` then that is also pointless since you already *have* the doctors

Comment: just use **doctor.id**

Comment: some points: 1. use doctor.id instead doctor_id.  2.change your query to doctor = Doctors.objects.get(pk=doctor.id)  3.where is pk?

Comment: ohhhh @MatsLindh thanks it turns out i didnt declare the doctor_id in the models.py folder....noob mistake ...btw if you give this as an answer i can accept it,if you would like